# PHP REST Client

Tags: php, rest, client

I have Java REST API Server with ServerResource to create hash code on some document, but I really don't know, how to built PHP rest client, can somebody help ? (Some example or tutorial how to do this ?) I have no experiences with php, so I'd appreciate help. How to connect to my local host through PHP ? How to POST some string to my hash resource in Java ?

I have downloaded rest client from phphttpclient.com/, so I choose some file, I have content of that file..now..how can I send it to my Java REST API (localhost:port/hash)?

Comment: you can use cURL - http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: have you actually hosted the php file? you do have a web server or something running? being able to execute a php file from disk is seperate from executing it using a url

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a very simple REST client in php to send request and receive responses in order to communicate with REST server. REST clients help you concentrate on your data to send instead of care about lower level thing like how to post or get data.
For simpler one, you should try HTTPFUL on if you use a framework like Zend, try Zend/Rest/Client

Answer (score 0):

This is not a primitive way to bulid a rest api in php,This will help you to startup it.

Here there are main you need to just create rest class in php,
I have given the main rest class in php.

```
<?php
class REST {
    // initialize the database connection 
    const DB_SERVER = "localhost";
    const DB_USER = "root";
    const DB_PASSWORD = "pass";
    const DB = "vtms";

    // set the conntent type and object to the api
    public $_allow = array();
    public $_content_type = "application/json";
    public $_request = array();

    private $_method = "";      
    private $_code = 200;

    //construct the  input for the rest call
    public function __construct(){
        $this->inputs();
    }

    //Set reference to the webserver
    public function get_referer(){
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }

   // give the status of the rest operation
    public function response($data,$status){
        $this->_code = ($status)?$status:200;
        $this->set_headers();
        echo $data;
        exit;
    }
    // For a list of http codes checkout http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
    private function get_status_message(){
        $status = array(
                    200 => 'OK',
                    201 => 'Created',  
                    204 => 'No Content',  
                    404 => 'Not Found',  
                    406 => 'Not Acceptable');
        return ($status[$this->_code])?$status[$this->_code]:$status[500];
    }

    public function get_request_method(){
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }
    // define curd operation of the api 
    private function inputs(){
        switch($this->get_request_method()){
            case "POST":
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_POST);
                break;
            case "GET":
            case "DELETE":
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($_GET);
                break;
            case "PUT":
                parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$this->_request);
                $this->_request = $this->cleanInputs($this->_request);
                break;
            default:
                $this->response('',406);
                break;
        }
    }       

    private function cleanInputs($data){
        $clean_input = array();
        if(is_array($data)){
            foreach($data as $k => $v){
                $clean_input[$k] = $this->cleanInputs($v);
            }
        }else{
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
                $data = trim(stripslashes($data));
            }
            $data = strip_tags($data);
            $clean_input = trim($data);
        }
        return $clean_input;
    }       
    // set headers to the content
    private function set_headers(){
        header("HTTP/1.1 ".$this->_code." ".$this->get_status_message());
        header("Content-Type:".$this->_content_type);
    }
}   
?>
```

If you copy and past this code without a any errors you almost done,Now create a class of the object extend to this rest api,example.

```
<?php
```

require_once("Rest.inc.php");

class API extends REST {

```
public $data = "";
private $db = NULL;
private $mysqli = NULL;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();    // Init parent contructor
    $this->dbConnect();     // Initiate Database connection
}

/*
 *  Connect to Database
 */

private function dbConnect() {
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(self::DB_SERVER, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD, self::DB);
}

/*
 * Dynmically call the method based on the query string
 */

public function processApi() {
    $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/", "", $_REQUEST['x'])));
    if ((int) method_exists($this, $func) > 0) {
        $this->$func();
    } else {
        $this->response('', 404);
    } // If the method not exist with in this class "Page not found".
}
  private function getAllstudent() {
    if ($this->get_request_method() != "GET") {
        $this->response('', 406);
    }

    $query = "SELECT * from students";
    $r = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die($this->mysqli->error . __LINE__);

    if ($r->num_rows > 0) {
        $result = array();
        while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
        $this->response($this->json($result), 200); // send user details
    }
    $this->response('', 204); // If no records "No Content" status
}

  private function json($data){
        if(is_array($data)){
            return json_encode($data);
        }
    }


}
$api = new API;
$api->processApi();
```

just open a .htaccess file and input this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/studentapi/method/ student.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Create table call student and input some values to it,And now open you browser and type this url,
http://localhost/yourserviceFodername/getAllStudent/studentapi/method/student.

Cheer up...